# C++ memcpy problem :(

Tags: c++, c, memcpy

I have a problem my src pointer of memcpy is pointing wrong.

`unsigned char* lpBuffer` is a buffer that contains my bytes, i checked with olly.

The code:

```
 IMAGE_DOS_HEADER iDOSh;
 memcpy(&iDOSh,lpBuffer,sizeof(iDOSh));
```

The problem is that `lpBuffer` points wrong, output from debugger is

```
dest = 002859E8 RIGHT
src = 000001D8 FALSE
```

`src` is pointing invalid :( i have no idea why

Thanks for reading

Comment: How are you getting the values of dest and src?

Comment: @Simon, the code you have there doesn't explain your problem.  If your pointer is bad, that's not `memcpy`'s fault.

Comment: The dest and src values i checked with olly , just BPed memcpy and looked at the stack

Comment: You will have to post a lot more code, like lpBuffer's definition and use.

Comment: Who/what is olly?  Is it the debugger?

Comment: lpBuffer just points to my exe file that is in memory
so the invalid ptr must be a fault of memcpy

Comment: Given that memcpy doesn't modify its parameters, I would think that's unlikely unless you manage to overwrite its contents. Without more code that shows how you set lpBuffer initially, it's pretty much impossible to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Simon, `memcpy` is a pass-by-value routine.  It **can not** change the value of `lpBuffer` given the code you have shown here.  Guaranteed.

Comment: Try:

    memcpy(&iDOSh,lpBuffer,sizeof(lpBuffer));

Comment: @Ben, if `lpBuffer` is defined as the OP says, that won't copy very much useful.

Comment: Please show the code that you've used to initialize `lpBuffer`. Whatever it is, it is incorrect, and the problem is there.

Comment: @Simon: you're probably looking at the wrong parameter: my guess is that `0x1d8` == `sizeof(iDOSH)`

Answer (score 4):

Why do you check with *ollydbg* but not something more convenient?? Trace your steps in your *IDE*. A pointer's value can't change become invalid when you pass it to `memcpy` function (because it's passed by value), so it means it has been invalid right before that `memcpy` call.

Unfortunately your code covers only that obvious `memcpy` call where ***"nothing can go wrong".***

Also to mention, that strange `0x00000YY` value for your pointer actually signs that something went wrong and probably you have invalid type cast somewhere in your code *(or something like that).*

Answer (score 1):

I think you are debugging in assembly calling C functions and trying to trace that with ollydbg (I just looked up what it is and based this assumption on their feature list).  This is very difficult to do.

I suggest that you do:

```
...
void print_ptr(void * p) {
     fprintf(stderr, "%p\n", p);
}
...
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER iDOSh;

    print_ptr(lpBuffer);
    memcpy(&iDOSh,lpBuffer,sizeof(iDOSh));
    print_ptr(lpBuffer);
```

If you aren't actually able to print things that will be ok.  Just make the functions `extern` to the file with the `memcpy` in question and it will force the compiler to load the value into the location which holds the first parameter.  You should be able to observe this in your debugger.

The likelihood the `memcpy` (from any reasonable C library) is actually doing something wrong is very very low.

If I had to guess what is going wrong it would be that `lpBuffer` is not actually supposed to be a `void *` but a linker label for a memory location.  In that case you might should try declaring it as:

```
extern char lpBuffer[];
```

and do your memcpy as

```
memcpy(&iDOSh,lpBuffer,sizeof(iDOSh));
```

or

```
extern IMAGE_DOS_HEADER lpBuffer;
```

and do your memcpy as

```
memcpy(&iDOSh,&lpBuffer,sizeof(iDOSh));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `lpBuffer` immediately before you call `memcpy` and again immediately afterwards.  Does it change?

If it changes, the only thing that could have changed the value in `lpBuffer` is the `memcpy`, which means that you are overwriting it in the call (i.e. it's not doing what you think it's doing ... double check your parameters).

My guess, though, looking at your code is that is probably not changing in the call to `memcpy`.  That is, if checking the value of `lpBuffer` immediately before and after shows it to be unchanged, you are inadvertantly changing it prior to calling `memcpy`.  You'll need to track that change down.